# Confusion about linear convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

In my textbook, it says that a sequence $\{P_n\}$ converges to $p$ , if posisitve Constants $\lambda$ and $\alpha$ exists with $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\left|p_{n+1}-p\right|}{\left|p_{n}-p\right|^{\alpha}}=\lambda$, then if $\alpha=1$ and $\lambda<1$, the sequence is linearly convergent.

However, when I am practicing a problem(linear convergence) as follows:

Show that for any positive integer $k,$ the sequence defined by $p_{n}=1 / n^{k}$ converges linearly to $p=0$.
The solution is :
$$
\frac{\left|p_{n+1}-0\right|}{\left|p_{n}-0\right|}=\frac{1 /(n+1)^{k}}{1 / n^{k}}=\frac{n^{k}}{(n+1)^{k}} \rightarrow 1
$$
as $n \rightarrow \infty$, we have that $p_{n}$ converges linearly to 0 for any integer $k>0$.

My question is, in the above solution, $\lambda=1$, how is this a linear convergence when referring to the definition?

Comment: It is not linearly convergent according to the definition.

Comment: @copper.hat The definition and the problem are from the same textbook so I don't know which one is right

Comment: Well, clearly $\lambda = 1$ in the example, so I don't know what to say. Some people call $\alpha=1$ to be linearly convergence (regardless of $\lambda$).\

Comment: @copper.hat ok so that value of $\lambda$ does not matter right, just the order $\alpha$ determines which type of convergence?

Comment: @JayEstrera It depends on the author.  There are two different conventions out there, but if you are going to talk about order of convergence $\alpha$ then it is usually taken to have no restriction on the rate $\lambda$.

Comment: @JayEstrera Unfortunately there are different conventions, you need to use whatever your context dictates. From a 'practical' perspective, linear is usually only useful when $\lambda <1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your textbook's definition is correct, your calculation is correct, but your test problem is poorly stated.

The case of $\alpha = 1$ and $\lambda=1$ is known as *sublinear* convergence. Linear convergence is slow, but sublinear convergence is fundamentally different and so slow that it is essentially useless in many practical application.

I will now explain the fundamental difference between linear convergence and the sequence given by $p_n = n^{-k}$.

In the case of linear convergence, we have
$$ |p_{n+1}| \approx \lambda |p_n| $$
for $n$ sufficiently large. There is no harm in assuming that
$$ |p_{n+1}| \approx \lambda |p_n| $$
for all $n$. If necessary, we simply discard the initial elements and renumber the rest. In short, linear convergence is characterized by
$$ |p_n| \approx \lambda^n |p_0|.$$
Let us consider the case where $p_n$ measures the error of some relevant computation. Then a relevant goal is to ensure that $$|p_n| \approx 10^{-m}$$ for some suitable value of $m$. Equivalently, we need
$$ n \log \lambda + \log|p_0| \approx -m \log(10) $$
or
$$ n(m) \approx \frac{-m \log(10) - \log|p_0|}{\log \lambda} = m \frac{\log 10}{-\log \lambda} + \frac{\log|p_0|}{- \log \lambda}$$
In particular, the number of iterations needed to decrease the error by a factor of $10$, is independent of $m$, because
$$ n(m+1) - n(m) \approx \frac{\log 10}{-\log \lambda}.$$

In the case of $p_n = \frac{1}{n^k}$ the situation is quite different. We have $$ |p_n| \approx 10^{-m}$$ if and only if $$ - k \log(n) \approx - m \log(10).$$
Equivalently
$$ n(m) \approx \exp \left(\frac{m \log(10)}{k}\right)$$
The number of extra iterations needed to decrease the error by a factor if $10$ is no longer independent of $m$, we have
$$ n(m+1) \approx n(m) \exp\left(\frac{\log(10)}{k}\right) = n(m) 10^{\frac{1}{k}}.$$
Typically, the computational cost (wall time, CPU cycles, energy consumption) is directly proportional to the number of iterations, so in the case of sublinear convergence the situation is dire. The cost of getting a single extra decimal is proportional to all the work we have already done. This explodes rapidly and explains why we really need a different label for the case $\lambda=1$.